# unable to post form values to controller using code igniter form

Tags: codeigniter

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('AdminHome/InsertMovieschedule'); ?>
 <?php echo form_input('MovieTitle',set_value('MovieTitle')); ?>
<?php echo form_error('MovieTitle'); ?>
<?php echo form_upload('MoviePic'); ?>
 <input type="submit" class="form_submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

unable post above form values to controller when i submit form it show empty array when i print array in controller some body help me

Comment: pls add your controller too

Answer (score 0):

Use attributes to pass to form_open like that

```
<?php  
   $attributes = array(
        'method'  => 'post'
    );
     echo form_open_multipart('AdminHome/InsertMovieschedule',$attributes);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
if($_POST)
{
//Here your post values
}
```